# Spring Boot 3.1.3 MultiTenancy + Authorization Server with Client_credentials how to authenticate users?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-authorization-server, userdetailsservice

Currently I am migrating the microservice from Spring Boot 2.7.* to Spring Boot 3.1.3, but for some reason the user credentials that I am passing as x-www-form-urlencoded values are not being picked up. UserDetails are not being loaded in the context, I need them loaded so I can modify the JWT token.

AuthorizationServer.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthorizationServer {

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        return new JdbcRegisteredClientRepository(jdbcTemplate);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer =
                new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer();

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .logout(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .addFilterBefore(new MultiTenancyInterceptor(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .apply(authorizationServerConfigurer);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this ?

I am expecting the request to look like this

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8001/login' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic ' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'username=' \
--data-urlencode 'password='
```

And the userdetails to be filled

Comment: Based on your description i`m understanding that before migration all worked great but now is some problems, can i see the previous(before migration) configuration class? as an update of question.

Comment: I would say it is similar to that  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt-legacy, basically I started from scratch because most of the things got deprecated. Probably I am misconfiguring something ?

Comment: i think you did some miss in new configuration and it is the reason why i asked you about previous config to see.

Comment: With the current config it is not picking up --data-urlencode 'username=user' \
--data-urlencode 'password=pass' any suggestions ?

Comment: here you should have `grant_type=password` not `'grant_type=client_credentials'` i recommend you to have a look [what-is-the-oauth2-password-grant](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/06/29/what-is-the-oauth2-password-grant).

Comment: Yeah I know, I want to switch to client_credentials and check the user so that I can get all authorities related to the user and add them to the access token.

Comment: [Multi-tenancy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.html) reference documentation, from here you can start

Comment: I added an answer. Notice that the `password` grant is not supported. This means that you cannot load a user's `UserDetails` into an `access_token` with `client_credentials`. If you want to load a user, use `authorization_code` grant instead.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Authorization Server [does not support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/126#issuecomment-704360472) the `password` grant type because it is deprecated in OAuth 2.1.

You do not need to pass the client credentials in both the `Authorization` header *and* the body of the request. Simply remove `--data-urlencode 'username='` and `--data-urlencode 'password='`.

Comment: I see that client_credentials is recommended for machine to machine communication, basically I want the same behaviour as password grant_type.

Client credentials: This grant type uses the client’s credentials to access protected data from a resource server. It’s suitable for machine-to-machine authentication.

Comment: As mentioned, the `password` grant type is deprecated. If you would still like to support it, you would need to add a custom extension to Spring Authorization Server. Though this isn't recommended, and you should switch to using `authorization_code`.

Comment: Is there a documentation how to configure the authorization server ?

Comment: Yes, docs are available at https://spring.io/projects/spring-authorization-server#learn